# Using not equal symbol in hive query

Tags: hive

I need to use '!=' symbol in my hive query with partitions.
I tried something like

```
from sample_table
insert overwrite table sample1
partition (src='a')
select * where act=10
insert overwrite table sample1
partition (src!='a')
select * where act=20
```

But it is showing error at '!=' symbol. How can i replace !=

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try to use [rlike/regex](https://cwiki.apache.org/Hive/languagemanual-udf.html#LanguageManualUDF-StringFunctions) function in hive to specify condition.

I think you can also use not operator `<>` not `!=`

Answer (score 3):

`partition (src!='a')` - what do you expect Hive to do - to write "select *" result into any partition instead of "a"? You see,  `partition (src='a')` means that you are writing result of aftergoing select statement into table's partition named "a". "PARTITION (a=b)" is not a conditional command like "WHERE a=b", you're just specifying how to name a partition. 
You have just to specify another partition name, so your query should look like:

`from sample_table insert overwrite table sample1 partition (src='a') select * where act=10 insert overwrite table sample1 partition (src='b') select * where act=20;`

After that you should see 2 new partitions "a" and "b" in table "sample1" with some data from these `select * where act=10` and `select * where act=20` queries respectively.

Answer (score 0):

may i know your hive version?
try using A <> B

Description from Hive DOCS:
NULL if A or B is NULL, TRUE if expression A is NOT equal to expression B, otherwise FALSE.